# searching for key in multidimensional array by sub array value

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I am trying to unset an array by value. I only have the `ExerciseID` and need to `unset` the array that it belongs too.

My array is structured like so:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 644
        [Sets] => 
        [Reps] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 33
        [Sets] => 
        [Reps] => 
    )
)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete element from multidimensional-array based on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and check for the `ExerciseID` key in your array with the value of your `ExerciseID` and if found , unset and break up from the loop.

```
$exid=33;
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    if($arr[$k]['ExerciseID']==$exid)
    {
        unset($arr[$k]);
        break;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ExerciseID] => 644
            [Sets] => 
            [Reps] => 
        )

)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/133347)