# WordPress: Upload images to ACF using repeater image field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My HTML form allows users to select any number of images to be uploaded to a custom post type. I've created a repeater field in ACF called 'images', of 'image' objects.

How do I save the uploaded images into that repeater field?

This is what I currently have:

```
$files = $_FILES['file'];
$image_number = 1;
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($files['name'][$key]) {
    $file = array(
      'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
      'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
      'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
      'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
    );
    $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => FALSE));
    update_sub_field( array('images', $image_number++, 'image'), $uploaded_file, $post_id);
  }
}
```

But the images aren't saved. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your use of the `update_field` function especially it's signature is wrong. You mixed up the parameters. Have a look here: [Wordpress ACF: How to add rows to a repeater field attached to a user via custom code (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879399/wordpress-acf-how-to-add-rows-to-a-repeater-field-attached-to-a-user-via-custom)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It is working for me. Although it's an old post, it might help someone else in future.

```
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $upload_dir . '/' . basename( $filename ),
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type']
);
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id);

$row = array(
        'name' => "Hello",
        'logo' => $attachment_id,  // this is where you put post id of your image
        'website' => "http://hello.com"
    );

add_row( "repeater_field", $row, $blog_post_id);
```

I also noticed that add_row works only if you have already at least one row. But if you want to add a new row, use update_field. Take a look here: [add_row in ACF Pro isn't saving repeater values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305000/add-row-in-acf-pro-isnt-saving-repeater-values)