# add_row in ACF Pro isn't saving repeater values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

### My Situation

I'm using [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](http://advancedcustomfields.com) to store metadata for a post in wordpress.

My posts are created dynamically (not through the administrative interface), which means that I explicitly need to populate metadata using field keys, not field names.  One of my fields is a repeater field with a single text area and another is a standard text area.

### My Code

The following code is what I call (once per post).  The post is created using `wp_insert_post()` earlier.

```
  // Populate "Name"
  update_field('field_566e360961c2f', 'John Doe', $wp_identifier);

  // Populate "Sponsors"
  foreach($sponsors as $sponsor) {

      // Define "Sponsor Name"
      $new_sponsor = array(
        'field_566e32fb943a5' => 'Beats and Corn Companye'
      );

      add_row('field_566e32bd943a4', $new_sponsor, $wp_identifier);
  }
```

The result of this is that standard text fields populate, and a single "sponsor" repeater item is created, but the value of the sponsor name is blank.

The relevant `wp_postmeta` data that is generated looks like this:

```
|   18226 |      71 | name                    | John Doe
|   19234 |      71 | sponsors                | 1                                                            |
|   19235 |      71 | _0_field_566e32fb943a5  | Beats and Corn Company                                                                             |
```

### My Question

What am I doing wrong?  Looking at the documentation for [`add_row()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_row/) this appears to be the correct approach.  Is it possible that repeater fields have a different way of notating keys that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't made incredibly clear in the documentation today, but it turns out `add_row` only works if an existing row had already been saved.  When trying to populate a repeater field for the very first time you have to use `update_field` instead and pass an array of value arrays.

### The corrected code:

```
  // Populate "Name"
  update_field('field_566e360961c2f', 'John Doe', $wp_identifier);

  // Populate "Sponsors"
  $new_sponsors = array();
  foreach($sponsors as $sponsor) {

      // Define "Sponsor Name"
      $new_sponsor = array(
        'field_566e32fb943a5' => 'Beats and Corn Companye'
      );
      $new_sponsors[] = $new_sponsor;
  }

  update_field('field_566e32bd943a4', $new_sponsors, $wp_identifier);
```

Comment: Note. To get field_id in Custom Fields > Fields Group > Field Keys check "Field Keys"

Comment: Adding on to what @KārlisMillers said, the "Field Keys" option can be checked in the Screen Options drop down.

Comment: I think add_row works now, even if there's no existing row. Worked for me after deleting all existing rows and then trying it.