# PHP - Delete from multi-dimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional PHP array and want to remove any elements (on a row basis) which do not match a value.

For example:

```
$user_types = [
    0 => ['ut_id' => 32, 'type' => 'admin'],
    1 => ['ut_id' => 31, 'type' => 'user'],
    2 => ['ut_id' => 801, 'type' => 'editor']
];
```

Let's say I only want the element where `'type' == 'admin'`. I want the output to be:

```
$user_types = [
     0 => ['ut_id' => 32, 'type' => 'admin']
]
```

I also need to ensure that the array is keyed sequentially. So if I only want `type == 'editor'` the array key should still be 0 (not 2), e.g.

```
 $user_types = [
     0 => ['ut_id' => 801, 'type' => 'editor']
 ]
```

I've had a look at [PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key) but this does not deal with multi-dimensional arrays.

I've also seen some solutions which use a `foreach` loop, but that seems quite inefficient.

Please can someone point me in the direction of what to look at? I can't find any examples that deal with this when it comes to **multidimensional** arrays. I have seen [Delete element from multidimensional-array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value) but this seems inefficient and was written about 6 years ago.

Comment: I would look into multi-dimensional array searches and go from there. I will note that numerically indexed arrays always start at `0`. You can't have a single element with a key of `2`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php in combination with `array_values`.

Comment: @StuartWagner Yes you can, there is no such restriction on the array key in php.

Comment: @jeroen You're absolutely right. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use php's [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function here:

```
<?php
$user_types = [
    0 => ['ut_id' => 32, 'type' => 'admin'],
    1 => ['ut_id' => 31, 'type' => 'user'],
    2 => ['ut_id' => 801, 'type' => 'editor']
];

$type = 'admin';
print_r(
    array_values(
        array_filter($user_types, function($entry) use ($type){
            return $entry['type'] === $type;
        })
    )
);

$type = 'editor';
print_r(
    array_values(
        array_filter($user_types, function($entry) use ($type){
            return $entry['type'] === $type;
        })
    )
);
```

The output of above code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ut_id] => 32
            [type] => admin
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ut_id] => 801
            [type] => editor
        )

)
```

Comment: Works perfectly and very efficient, Thank you. Will accept as the answer in a few mins when SO allows me to :)