# How to delete an array inside an array based on value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have an array in session

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store1"
    "product" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store2"
    "product" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store3"
    "product" => "4"
  ]
]
```

I made a function that to remove arrays that matches the value of store when given. for instance I give `store1` it should remove `store1` array and outputs like this

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store2"
    "product" => "2"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store3"
    "product" => "4"
  ]
]
```

Instead I get the output

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => "store2"
  2 => "store3"
]
```

My function

```
function removeFromSessionArray($name, $value)
{
    return session()->put($name, array_diff(session()->get('stores'), [$value]));
}
```

Can someone tell how can me achieve the possible output?

PS. Learning arrays.

Comment: Have a look at [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).It allows you to select the content of the resulting array by defining criteria (inside a callback function).

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4466437/4668162

Comment: @Onix Look at answer of Ali Rasheed! It worked pretty well. It uses same logic and is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$m = session('products');
    for($i=0;$i<count($m);$i++)
    {
        if($m[$i]['store']==$username)
        {
            unset($m[$i]['store']);
            unset($m[$i]['product']);
        }
    }

    dd(array_values(array_filter($m)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple index ([store value].[product value]) for this array, something like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  'store1.1' => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store1"
    "product" => "1"
  ]
  'store2.2' => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store2"
    "product" => "2"
  ]
  'store3.4' => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store3"
    "product" => "4"
  ]
]
```

And after these changes you can simply delete any value from the session array