# Laravel, how to delete key and value in an array of a specific position?

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it all. I want to delete the highlighted section in `yellow` as shown in picture below. And rest remain unchanged. What is the best way to do it? Is there a method that does't  use foreach?

[image]

Comment: See this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value

Answer (score 2):

you can do this just with one foreach!

```
foreach ($data as $key => $subArr) {
    unset($subArr['id']);
    $data[$key] = $subArr;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following

```
$filteredArray = array_map(function($array) {
    unset($array['id']);
    return $array;
}, $dataArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `foreach()` loop on the array, You can go with `array_search()`

```html
$results=array_search($unwantedValue,$array,true);
if($results !== false) {
  unset($array[$result]);   
}
```